# Symfony2/Doctrine: SQL to DQL for a querybuilder in a repository to make a search form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

In my project with Symfony, I need to make a search form with multicriteria.
I have a select for the entity Parc, a select for the entity Typesactivite and an input text for Ensembles.

I have this **SQL** request:

```
SELECT distinct e.nom FROM `ensembles` e, `parcsimmobilier` p, `batiments` b, `batiments_typesactivite` bta, `typesactivite` ta WHERE e.parcsimmobilier_id=p.id AND b.ensembles_id=e.id AND bta.batiments_id=b.id AND bta.typesactivite_id = ta.id AND p.nom="Ville de Dijon" AND ta.type="Sport"
```

This SQL request gives me all ensembles which belong to the Dijon parc where the batiments have Sport for activity.

I tried to transform this SQL request in **DQL** syntax in my EnsemblesRepository.php but it not gives me the good result, I think I do it wrong:

```
public function recherche($input) //$input est la valeur entrée dans l'input type text recherche
    {
        $qb = $this ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->select('e.nom')
                    ->addSelect('e.parcsimmobilier')
                    ->from('MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Parcsimmobilier', 'p')
                    ->from('MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Typesactivite', 'ta')
                    ->from('MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Batiments', 'b')
                    ->where('e.parcsimmobilier = p.id')
                    ->andWhere('b.ensembles=b.id')
                    ->andWhere('ta.batiments=b.id')
                    ->andWhere('e.nom LIKE :input')
                    ->setParameters(array(
                        'input' => "%".$input."%"));

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

When I submit the form, I have these errors:

> [2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 16 near
>   'parcsimmobilier': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a
>   StateFieldPathExpression.
>
> [1/2] QueryException: SELECT e.nom, e.parcsimmobilier FROM
>   MySpace\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Ensembles e,
>   MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Parcsimmobilier p,
>   MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Typesactivite ta,
>   MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Batiments b WHERE e.parcsimmobilier = p.id AND
>   b.ensembles=b.id AND ta.batiments=b.id AND e.nom LIKE :input

**How can I make the DQL request in my repository?**

This is the search form I submit for make a search on my entity Ensembles:

```
class RechercheType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            //Parcsimmobilier
            ->add('parcs:', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Parcsimmobilier', 
                'property' => 'nom', 
                'empty_value' => 'Choisir le parc immobilier', 
                'required' => true))

            //Typesactivite
            ->add('typesactivite:', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Typesactivite', 
                'property' => 'type', 
                'empty_value' => 'Choisir le type d\'activite', 
                'required' => false))

            //Ensembles
            ->add('ensemble', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'rechercher'), 
                'required' => false))
            ;
```

---

**UPDATE**

There is my code for the controller, if it could helps:

```
public function rechercheEnsemblesAction() {

        $formRecherche = $this->createForm(new RechercheType());

        //si la méthode est bien en POST
        if ($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST' ) 
        {
            $formRecherche->bind($this->get('request'));
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $ensemble = $em ->getRepository('MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Ensembles')
                            ->recherche($formRecherche['ensemble']
                            ->getdata());

        }

        return $this->render('MySpaceGestionPatrimoinesBundle:Ensembles:rechercheEnsembles.html.twig', array('ensemble' => $ensemble, 'formRecherche' => $formRecherche->createView() ));
    }
```

Let's try to do the **query** ***step by step***.

In a **select** tag, I can choose the **name** of the parcs (**required** in my form), **without** enter a value in my input text for the name of **ensemble**. 
My **SQl** request is on **phpMyAdmin**:

```
SELECT distinct e.nom  FROM `ensembles` e, `parcsimmobilier` p where e.parcsimmobilier_id=p.id
```

This request gives me **all ensemble**s belonging to the **parc with id 1**.

In **DQl**, I try this in my repository **EnsemblesRepository.php**:

```
public function recherche() //$input est la valeur entrée dans l'input type text recherche
{
    $qb = $this ->createQueryBuilder('e')
                ->select('e.nom')
                ->from('MySpaceDatabaseBundle:Parcsimmobilier', 'p')
                ->where('e.parcsimmobilier = p.id')
                ->andWhere('e.nom LIKE :input')
                ->setParameters(array(
                    'input' => "%".$input."%"));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

But it doesn't return me the good result. The result is all Ensemble in my database even if I choose a parc in my select tag create in my buildform.

Someone could help me step by step?

If you need more information, this the relation between my entities. Only two classes/entities have the relation I need.

**Ensemnles.php**:

```
/**
     * @var \Parcsimmobilier
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parcsimmobilier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parcsimmobilier_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $parcsimmobilier;
```

**Batiments.php**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MySpace\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Ensembles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $ensembles;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MySpace\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Typesactivite")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $typesactivite;
```

I really can't find the solution, do not hesitate to ask for more informations if you need.

Thank you for your comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27967155/symfony2-datatable-bundle-error-set-a-datatable-id-in-your-action-with-setda/27981233#27981233), check the Jquery datatables [here](http://datatables.net/manual/installation), for your project if it's to manage your entities in Symfony.

Then, you can use your own request with Jquery, Ajax and Symfony to have some results for a search form in an html `<table>`.

This is an example of `.js` you can use for search in datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
        responsive: true,
        initComplete: function () {
            var api = this.api();
            api.columns().indexes().flatten().each( function ( i ) {
                var column = api.column( i );
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    });
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                });
            });
        }
    });
    $("div.toolbar").html('<b>Example</b>');
});
```

And of course the `html` (don't forget the structure for a table using DataTables, all step are in the doc **=> For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (thead) and a body (tbody). An optional footer (tfoot) can also be used**.):

```
<table id="dataTables" class="your class or bootstrap class if you are using bootstrap for example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            ...number you want...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ entity.field }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.field2 }}</td>
            ...etc..
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm trying to integrate my project right now , thank you, it's helpful.

Comment: @Julien, here are some links to help you in different case you need for your application: [bundles for symfony](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19490/datatables-with-symfony2) and here too: [github code for datas integration](https://gist.github.com/Slauta/3175282)

Answer (score 1):

You try to select an object with an alias. If you want to select scalar fields use `select('entity_alias.field')` but if you want to select an entity you just specify the table alias. In your case you need to select 'p' instead of 'e.parcsimmobilier'.

Also you should always join instead of using multiple from statements. This will also allow you to drop those where statements as doctrine joins depending on your object model so you don't need to write those Id = id manually.

Comment: I try your solution, but it didn't work. Indeed, the result is too weird, it returns me only two ensembles which they not belong to the same parc. Thank you for the help. I continue to search for a solution. Check my update of my question by the way, maybe it could help.